What is the best way to get the latest transactions for an SPL token, and how can I calculate the price impact of those transactions?
I am working on monitoring the transactions over many SPL tokens. Currently I've setup a webhook from Helius and getting SWAP transactions of the token but I'm unable to figure out how can I calculate what price impact it made.
I just is there any other way to watch over latest transactions of the token and how do I calculate the price impact of it ?
